# PHP5.2.3 for debian etch?

Tags: debian, php5

Is it possible to get PHP5.2.3 for debian etch?

Comment: Download and install from source. THis question does not seem to be related to programming.

Comment: This should be migrated to Super User.

Answer (score 1):

Another way could be download the source and repackage it for etch (like a backport). However i think the dependences issues could make this task very difficult.

Easy way: upgrade to Lenny.